# Going back to Windows, but don't know how?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have installed Ubuntu and thought I dual-booted it... But I didn't, so now I wanna go back to Windows (I have a Windows 8 CD) but when I insert the disk into CD/DVD drive and change my boot menu it still boots in to Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu over Win7 Home Premium using a LiveCD, it's said that no filesystem was recognized on my laptop, so I thought it was automatically placed on the unallocated partition that I've created. But it didn't, so it just deleted my Windows partition and installed Ubuntu on it.

What is the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks!

EDIT: I don't know much about computers but i just got this hp pavvilion dm1 whit windows 8 isntalled on it and updated it to 8.1

i installed ubuntu the this way: making a new partition, and making the swap and boot or something my self by clicking ''something else"

ps: i don't have a dvd drive

Comment: Could you please add more info in-detail, such as was the windows an OEM, how did you exactly performed the Ubuntu installation.. etc. This will help us to assist you better :)

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed it over Windows 7 home premium 

My laptop is an Acer Intel Core i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4

Comment: I should have mentioned to [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/416755/edit) you question and add more detail while commenting. Sorry for that. Could you also add the way you installed. Is it on a separate partition or onto the same partition?

Answer (score 0):

If you've overwritten the Windows partition with Ubuntu, there's no way to 'recover' the Windows install.
You will have to reinstall Windows from a Windows CD/DVD.
Reinstalling Windows is outside the scope of this forum, but you'll find plenty of guides on the web.